# Can't get width of image changed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page displaying a single image out of a number of images. I have all images stored in a json object (photoarr) so to navigate back and forth I use this function:

```
function setPhoto(index) {
  var photo = photoarr[index];
  $('#photoId').text(photo.id);
  $('#photo').attr({ 'src': photo.url, 'alt': photo.title });
  $('#photoTitle').text(photo.title);
  $('#photoWidth').text(photo.width);
  $('#photoHeight').text(photo.height);
  $('#photoTitle').width($('#photo').width());
}
```

My challenge is that when I get to the last line trying to set the `#photoTitle` width to match the `#photo` width `$('#photo').width()` is 0 (zero).

It's as if I need to "flush" the DOM changes I've made to actually get the new image width...

If any of the above makes sense please let me know what to do...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
function setPhoto(index) {
  var photo = photoarr[index];

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = photo.url;
  img.onload = function(){

    $('#photoId').text(photo.id);
    $('#photo').attr({ 'src': this.src, 'alt': photo.title });
    $('#photoTitle').text(photo.title);
    $('#photoWidth').text(this.width);
    $('#photoHeight').text(this.height);
    $('#photoTitle').width(this.width);

  }
}
```